# Auto Run a php file with Javascript on hosting server

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

I need to run a PHP file on my server (on hostinger, a hosting site ) at some schedules , let say every hour, I am working with a Firebase Realtime Database, I tried CRON but the Javascript is not working . Any idea on how implement this every hour?

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.somesite.com');
$somediv= $html->find('somediv',0);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.8.0/firebase.js">
</script>
</head>       
<body>   
<script> 
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/",
storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var myFirebase = firebase.database().ref();
var recommendations = myFirebase.child('somechild').child('somediv').set("<?
php echo $somediv; ?>");

</script>

<?php echo $somediv; ?><br />

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP read some div from some site and catch the elements to be stored on my Firebase database

Comment: you would have to hit the script with a client that can run js.such as installing a web browser on the server to do it

Comment: javascript is only executed within a browser

Comment: Yes, I understand that js only can be executed on a browser, so my question is, can I execute this file on my hosting server?

Comment: What part of that file? The php part can get executed if your provider offers the execution of php. If you want to run the js part, maybe read about node.js